# anyObject converted into a string

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

i'm trying to convert the object with the key price into an NSString, but whatever i do i keep getting lldb error on following line

```
arrayDic.setValue(object.objectForKey("price") as NSString, forKey: "price")
```

When i remove it there is no error. The object.objectForKey("price") is number type in parse database. How can i convert it into a string correctly?

the code:

```
func loadItems() {
    var query = PFQuery(className:"Items")
    query.orderByAscending("createdAt")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {


            for object in objects {

                arrayDic.setValue(object.objectForKey("price") as NSString, forKey: "price")
                arrayDic.setValue(image, forKey: "image")



            }


        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog("Error: %@ %@", error, error.userInfo!)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Breakup the statement into multiple statements to find where the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `object.objectForKey("price")` is number type in parse database

Then why are you saying it's a string? Remember, saying `as` does not *convert* anything; it is a claim about the truth. If you lie, of course you will crash. Do not lie!

I assume that it is an NSNumber. If I'm right, then say `as NSNumber`.

And since this thing *is* a number, you should not *want* to store it as a string in `arrayDic`, so just leave it as a number.

(Also, if `arrayDic` is a dictionary, you should not be using `valueForKey:` - you can, but it's silly and roundabout, and can have unintended consequences.)